# OLS regression in stata. Dummy dependent variable vs if== at the end of the coding

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, stata

I have the following regression.

Y(tcs)= X1(tcs), X2(tcs), X3(tcs), u

t= time, I have eleven years
c= countries, I have 34 countries
s= sector, I have two sectors, let's name them a and b.

I created a series of dummies so I have Ya Yb X1a X1b X2a X2b, etc.. I run three models:

1) Ya= X1a X2a X3a

2) Y= X1 X2 X3 if sector==A

3) Y= X1a X1b X2a X2b X3a X3b

While it is clear to me what happens in option 2), Stata takes just the observation that have a sector a (in fact observations are half of my total), I don't understand what Stata does (from a maths/regression point of view) in option 1).

Option 3) I guess it's the least correct one if, as I understood, it looks at the effect of X1a and X1b (and the others) on the entire set of my variable Y.

Also any comments on what is the most correct model to understand the impact of X1a on Ya?

Comment: Hey, welcome to CV! Have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a reference how to properly format math in your questions.

Comment: Given that you have mulitple time points and sectors, you should not be using OLS as you will violate the assumption of independent errors.

Comment: No details here on the Stata command you used.